# Syslog RFC 5424 client library - C++

Tags: c++, c, logging, syslog

Are you aware of any decent permissively (LGPL) licensed (or not, in which case I'd use it for reference) network syslog library (RFC5424) in C++ (or even C, bindings are not very difficult to write).

I found [liblogging.org](http://www.liblogging.org/), but it's been pretty much abandoned in 2005-8.

Ideas?

Comment: The last update is version 0.7.1 from 2008-05-06 (need to visit download page to see this). From the project home page it appears 2005 was the last update.

Comment: I found this question perfectly relevant (even if not 100% perfectly formed). Objectively speaking, by quick look it *seems* the mentioned library was last updated 2005. Was the quick conclusion of this project being "abandoned" due to long time no updates the reason for closing this question? I do not see any provocation for debate here even if OP's conclusion is either hastened or the OP did not bother providing details about coming to this conclusion.

Comment: Actually, the conclusion was based on the fact that Rainer Gerhards, the author of liblogging.org moved on to developing rsyslogd and windows logging packages.